# Does .length in javascript iterate through the whole array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm an front end webdev intern at a small company where I'm making a panel which displays database statistics.

Now I noticed that on my panel which gives the count for how many entries are in a specific array the specific stat always takes a while to load (my other statistics appear nearly instantly).

Now my question is, does array.length actually loop though the whole array to get it's length?
The length is about 17000 and takes about 5 seconds to appear so I'm guessing that's the time it takes to loop through such a big array.

Comment: Make SURE you do this in a for loop: `for (var i=0,n=arr.length;i<n;i++)`

Comment: In which browser are you seeing this?

Comment: No. It does not.

        var arr = [];
        arr[0] = 1;
        arr[1000000000] = 2;

        var start = Date.now();
        var len = arr.length;
        var timeUsed = Date.now() - start;
        console.log('Length:', len, 'Time used:', timeUsed);

See how long that took? 0.

Comment: With large arrays I agree with @mplungjan and explicitly set the length so on each iteration `.length` isn't checked. However, I'd like to say it depends on what you're actually doing in the loop as many JavaScript engines are good at optimizing these things.

Answer (score 1):

It is implementation dependent. The optimal implementation should know its length, where as the lazy one would iterate to figure this out.

Comment: I don't think this is true. `length` is a regular property of Arrays, it's assignable. No implementation is free to dynamically compute it. You can assign any integer to the `length` property to grow or shrink the array.

Comment: @meagar - if you add or remove stuff from the array the length will change

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, because the array will update the length property on itself as you add or remove elements, but it does *not* dynamically compute the length.